# Is it possible to set Windows 10 to save memory dumps to an external drive?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, bsod, dump

I have a new but cheap and underpowered netbook which came with Windows 10 and has some issues I'm trying to sort out.

This is hindered by the fact that the internal storage is quite small so every time there's a BSOD Windows deletes the memory dump because there's not enough space on the drive to keep it.

Now I do have a 1TB external drive. I would love to get Windows to store the memory dumps there. I've Googled the issue and so far can't find help elsewhere.

An acceptable workaround would be if there's a setting to tell Windows not to automatically delete the dumps each time. This would give me the chance to manually move them to the external drive.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/204214-dump-file-change-default-location.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

I found the answer at [**Windows Memory Dumps: What Exactly Are They For?** on the **How-To Geek** forum](http://www.howtogeek.com/196672/windows-memory-dumps-what-exactly-are-they-for/). This is the important dialog with the settings that you can get to via Control Panel:

[image: Startup and Recovery dialog]

You can actually change both settings I mentioned. You can provide an alternate path for the memory dumps **or** you can tell Windows not to delete the dumps when there's not much space on the drive.